# How to declare parameter type according to class method return type?

Tags: typescript

for example :

```
    export const mock = <T>(provide, key: keyof T, value) => (){}
    class Service {
      do(): boolean {
        return true;
      }
    }
    // value have to be Boolean 
    mock<Service>(Service, "do", true)
```

the value parameter is the type of return type of the `T[key]` function.
I wonder if it is possible to declare the type of value somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution:

```js
/**
 * If T is a Class, return union string type of class methods
 */
type ClassType<T> = T extends { new(): infer R } ? keyof R : never

/**
 * Check if property is a function/method
 */
type AnyFunc = (...args: any[]) => any

export const mock = <P,>(provide: P, key: ClassType<P>, value: P extends { new(): infer R } ? R[keyof R] extends AnyFunc ? ReturnType<R[keyof R]> : never : never) => {}

class Service {
  do(): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}



const reuslt = mock<typeof Service>(Service, 'do', false) // ok
const reuslt2 = mock<typeof Service>(Service, 'foo', false) // error, expected do
const reuslt3 = mock<typeof Service>(Service, 'do', 42) // error, expected boolean
```

Please keep in mind, TS treats `Service` type and `typeof Service` in different ways.

Because, I'm not an explanation master, here is your example:

```js
const x: Service = {
  do: () => true
}

const y: typeof Service = class {
  do() {
    return true
  }
}
```

TypeScript class [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)

**UPDATE**
Handle promises

```js
/**
 * If T is a Class, return union string type of class methods
 */
type ClassType<T> = T extends { new(): infer R } ? keyof R : never

/**
 * Check if property is a function/method
 */
type AnyFunc = (...args: any[]) => any

type PromiseReturnType<T> = T extends Promise<infer R> ? R : T

export const mock = <P,>(provide: P, key: ClassType<P>, value: P extends { new(): infer R } ? R[keyof R] extends AnyFunc ? PromiseReturnType<ReturnType<R[keyof R]>> : never : never) => { }

class Service {
  do() {
    return new Promise<number>(resolve => resolve(42))
  }
}


const reuslt = mock<typeof Service>(Service, 'do', false) // ok
const reuslt2 = mock<typeof Service>(Service, 'foo', false) // error, expected do
const reuslt3 = mock<typeof Service>(Service, 'do', Promise.resolve(42)) // error, expected number
const reuslt4 = mock<typeof Service>(Service, 'do', 42) // ok
```

Comment: thanks, it is work, but what if do  function return promise ?

Comment: mock<typeof Service>(Service, 'do', Promise.resolve(45))

Comment: thanks,  it is not possible to get promise return type?

Comment: change your answer to export const mock = <T, P = new () => T>(... ) and  you can use - @mock<UserService>(UserService, "validateAndGetUser", { fName: "", lName: "a" })